# Heart Shape LED Blinking

Tags: transistors, amplifier

I am going to be connecting a 9 Volt battery to a bunch of LEDs (14 specifically in a row) I plan to oscillate them on and off, half, and half.  The shape of the LEDS, is a heart so like that I get half a heart lighting up, and the other half lighting up, because I have to recite a love poem written by Shakespeare for my English class; anyway, I have several resistors of various capacitors but I have this one capacitor I have that was in a robot that oscillated turning its eyes(LEDs) on and off its a 2N3904.

### My Inventory

**2N2222, 2N3906, 8050, MC7812CT transistor**

**Capacitors**

**Resistors**

**Decade Counter/Divider with 10 Decoded Outputs
Divide-by-8 Counter/Divider with 8 Decoded Outputs**

**AND,OR, XOR,NAND, NOR gates**

**1 Extra 9 Volt Battery**

**Several 1.5 Volt Battery**

What modifications do I need to make to this circuit to make a blinking heart with 7 diodes being on each side, adding up to a total of 14 RED LEDs?

##NOTE##
I am sorry but I do not know how to get dielectric capacitors on circuit lab, but the capacitors are dielectric.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr5yRG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your current circuit will put mere uA through the LEDs. They certainly won't light up.

Comment: @user2943160 Even while using the transistor(s) because I did not know how to add them with such a numerous amount of LEDs?

Comment: LEDs have a voltage drop that varies with the LED colour.  The total voltage drop of a group of series-connected LEDs must be less than the power supply voltage.  There are a great many articles in this Stackesxchange on using LEDs - use the Search, or just look through the "Related" aricles that appear to the right of your question.

Comment: @Sigma6RPU: Would that be 7 LEDs on each side? Can you accept a modest 20mA per LED, for brightness? Would you be willing to consider a 555 or 7555 IC and a few resistor and capacitor parts? Or does it have to use 2N3904 BJTs? What's the blinking period? Please update your question with some more information.

Comment: @jonk Yes I have a 555 timer chip I just supposed because I saw the robot function using a 2N3904 transistor, and a few capacitors  I thought it would work.  And yes 7 on each side of the heart.

Comment: @jonk My inventory is quite big of low voltage capacitors and transistors, and ICs

Comment: @Sigma6RPU: Much improved question. Thanks.

Comment: BTW your circuit is called an astable oscillator

Comment: @Passerby Good sir, my electronics teacher in high school didn't teach me jack about transistors, transistor logic, and a bunch of other stuff to lengthy to mention. But thanks that is useful to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. Let's go with your existing design. The NPN BJTs are rated for a maximum of about \$I_c=100mA\$ or so, so I think they should be fine. They will see a maximum load of about \$60mA\$, so within their limitations. I think those \$100\mu F\$ caps can probably manage the base currents. And also the typical \$9V\$ alkaline battery can in fact deliver \$100mA\$ if asked. So I'm going to leave everything alone except for adding in the sets of LEDs you want to insert. I'll assume that you want about \$20mA\$ in each of them. You can adjust the current limit resistors as you see fit, of course. Here's the very slightly modified schematic without the switch you added (you can work that out, I think):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1RzHk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I didn't do much by way of calculation. I just figured I would use the LEDs in at most three per series chain and at least two. So this worked out to three parallel sections for each side in order to get all seven LEDs (into each side.) A very simple mental note was to divide up your \$9V\$ into 5 *pieces* of \$1.8V\$ each. At \$20mA\$ this works out to \$90\Omega\$ per *piece*. So each parallel branch has exactly five of these pieces in series. That made it very easy to work out the resistor values. If I had two LEDs in series, then I needed the resistor to account for the other three pieces (\$3\cdot 90\Omega=270\Omega\$.) If I had three LEDs in series, then I needed the resistor to account for the other two pieces (\$2\cdot 90\Omega=180\Omega\$.) That's pretty gross calculations, but it probably won't get too far from the mark. You can always just adjust from there based upon what you see.

I added a nice big cap, \$C_3\$, across your \$9V\$ battery. Try the circuit with and without it see if it makes any difference to you.

(The currents in the branches won't exactly match. So once you get it built and working, you can check to see if the LEDs are noticeably different in brightness. Hopefully not. But if so, just adjust the resistor values or insert another resistor in series to tweak them.)

That's an answer in keeping with what you wrote up, I think. I've never attempted to build this, though. And I might use a starter resistor on one side to make sure it powers up consistently. But I think it's got a shot.

Comment: You know, your answers are always (95%) right, but imho always ranty or wordy. I'm sure you'll go far here even without changing your methods, but maybe just a FYI for future consideration. +1 as usual. Only difference I would have done was 3, 3, 1 led, but that's really just semantics :)

Comment: @Passerby: Thanks. (I think.) I am a hobbyist without any training whatsoever. So I apologize for the 5% errors I'm making. Please feel free to kick me in the shins when I need it. I don't mind it. By the way, I considered 3:3:1, too. Just flipped a coin to decide, really.

Comment: Flip a coin, or based on whatever resistors are on hand or what wiring is easier. And I just wanted to point out the good job you are doing :)

Comment: @Passerby: Thanks. :) I suppose the wordiness comes from teaching as an adjunct at a 4yr university for a while and trying to reach students there. It is hard to find the right pace and I often feel as though I should write either a great deal more or else a lot less. But I just don't have the time to do either. ;)

Comment: @jonk If they are dim I think I might just wire another 9V in parallel, so like that I get more current at the same voltage. but thanks.

Comment: @jonk The two couple of 270 Ohm resistors could they be added together in parallel and only use one resistor?

Comment: @Sigma6RPU: No. Don't do that. You need all the resistors shown.